# How to compare 2 characters with strcmp in c?

Tags: c, strcmp

I am trying to compare 2 characters with using strcmp. I gave statements but when I enter a and a as two characters, it gives -1. I don't see why? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ARR_SIZE 20

int main()
{
    //comparing to characters
    char c1[1], c2[1];
    int result;
    //asking user to enter characters respectively
    printf("6.Enter the first character you want to compare: \n");
    scanf("%s", c1);
    getchar();
    printf("7.Enter the second character you want to compare: \n");
    scanf("%s", c2);
    getchar();
    //comparing c1 with c2 using strcmp
    //result = strcmp(c1, c2);
    if (strcmp(c1, c2) == 0)
    {
        printf("0\n");
    }
    else if (c1 < c2)
    {
        printf("-1\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("1\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `char[1]` is a *zero length* C string. Remember the NUL terminator!

Comment: Avoid grief, do not use `scanf("%s", ....`  Research `fgets()`.

Comment: regarding; `if (strcmp(c1, c2) == 0)`  The function: `strcmp()` compares NUl terminated strings BUT those single characters in `c1[1]` and `c2[1]` are not strings, Rather then are a couple of individual characters

Answer (score 2):

You have a buffer overflow. [Don't use `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).

Even if your input was only a single `char`, you would still need another in `c1` and `c2` for the termination: `'\0'`:

```
    char c1[2], c2[2];
```

Also, you are comparing the memory addresses since `c1` and `c2` are `char` arrays. Compare the `char`s instead: `c1[0] < c2[0]`

```
    if (strcmp(c1, c2) == 0)
  {
    printf("0\n");
  }
    else if (c1[0] < c2[0])
  {
    printf("-1\n");
  }
    else
  {
    printf("1\n");
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of the buffers being completely useless for storing C strings. They're not big enough.

Comment: Pedantically, the `strcmp()` compare is done as if the characters were `unsigned char` and not `char` so `c1[0] < c2[0]` needs a little work.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because:
you doing getchar after doing a scanf! The second input will be taken in by getchar and c2 will be allocated some garbage value.

Also: You should compare the characters: so c1[0] < c2[0] rather than c1 < c2

Answer (score 0):

I made a small improvement on @mkayaalp 's answer and my code worked properly. Here:

```
    if (c1[0] == c2[0])
  {
    printf("0\n");
  }
    else if (c1[0] < c2[0])
  {
    printf("-1\n");
  }
    else
  {
    printf("1\n");
  }
```

I also changed the if part.